# xlsxwriter format for pattern seems... buggy?

Tags: xlsxwriter

So I tried to apply a pattern with a format class in xlsxwriter.

```
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Temp.xlsx")
sheet = wb.add_worksheet()

blank_pattern_format = wb.add_format({
            'align':'center',
            'valign' : 'vcenter',
            'border' : 1,
            'shrink' : True,
            'font_size' :10,
            'bold' : True,
            'pattern' : 4,
})

sheet.write("A1","",blank_pattern_format)
wb.close()
```

I wanted the forth pattern which is "25% gray" in Excel. But the outcome is just solid black for that cell.
The interesting part is, when I check the property of that black cell, it actually shows that it has None color for bg_color, and also "25% gray" pattern is applied to that cell.

I tried to copy the format to other cell in excel. And it turned to the solid black one as well.

But when I got into the cell property again, and chose the exact same pattern("25% gray")(which was shown as already being chosen), and clicked confirm without adjusting anything else, it now shows as 25% gray pattern and not the solid black one.

I think this means there can be a bug in xlsxwriter module for patterns. Is there I can do to fix this case? Or any walk-around maybe? (Documents about pattern in format class was short and not that helpful to fix this case)

Hope you guys can enlighten me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edited the code to be more convenient for you to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a bug. There are some odd Excel edge conditions when the foreground and background colors aren't specified. I'll look into it.

In the meantime you can work around the issue by specifying a background color:

```py
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('temp.xlsx')
sheet = wb.add_worksheet()

blank_pattern_format = wb.add_format({
    'align': 'center',
    'valign': 'vcenter',
    'border': 1,
    'shrink': True,
    'font_size': 10,
    'bold': True,
    'pattern': 4,
    'bg_color': 'white',
})

sheet.write('A1', '', blank_pattern_format)
wb.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you jmcnamara! It will help me with white bg_colorfor now :) I also read your reply in github! Thank you for working in that as well. Hope you can find a fix! Again, thank you for the awesome library!